# Generate CDATA in XML using groovy MarkupBuilder

Tags: xml, groovy, markupbuilder

I want to be able to generate a CDATA portion in my XML using Groovy. I have used the mkp of the MarkupBuilder to do that, but it's not working. I am looping through products and then generate the following snippet as part of the XML. I get the following instead: It prints the unescaped text next to the product code instead of in the description, which is left blank.

```
  <product>
     <name>banana</name>
     <code>10002</code><name>ICON_1</name><!CDATA[This product is on 
                                                     sale]]]>
     <description/>
   </product>
```

Here is the portion which In use to generate the data.

```
 product{
    name (product.name)
    code (product.code)
    description mkp.yieldUnescaped("<!CDATA[${product.description}]]>")
}
```

This is what I want to print:

```
<product>
   <name>banana</name>
   <code>10002</code>
   <description><![CDATA[This product is on sale]]></description>
</product>
```

Comment: Why do you care if it is CDATA? If you are using XML APIs to generate the XML, it will escape content for you. Most of the time that people think they need CDATA, they don't.

Comment: It is not my design. A third party api needs it, so I have no choice

Comment: That’s usually a sign that they are doing things wrong. string parsing, instead of using XML parsers and APIs

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately cannot influence the design.

Comment: For parser it should be faster to parse big chunk of data exactly in cdata section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use some curly braces around your `CDATA` section to give the builder a hint of where to place it:

```
def out = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(out)

xml.product {
    name ('banana') 
    code ('10002')
    description { mkp.yieldUnescaped("<![CDATA[Example of text in a CDATA block]]>") }
}

System.out.println out.toString()
```

This produces:

```
<product>
  <name>banana</name>
  <code>10002</code>
  <description><![CDATA[Example of text in a CDATA block]]></description>
</product>
```

Comment: I really appreciate this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this code is broken if "Example of text in a CDATA block" contains another cdata section.